# how to retrive current active order in ibapi?

Tags: python, active-directory, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I am beginner to implement interactive brokers api in Python.Now, I am confusing about checking active order function from ibapi. I just want to get the current active order ID , but not all the historical order ID. Furthermore, it would be A one-cancels-the-other (OCO) order.However, My code list all the  order ID

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import datetime
import threading
import time
import pandas
from ibapi.order import Order
import pandas as pd



class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data =[]# Initialize variable to store candle
        self.order_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[ 'OrderId', 'Symbol', 'Status'])
    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
       # print(f'DateTime: {bar.date}  Open: {bar.open}  High: {bar.high} Close: {bar.close}  Low: {bar.low}  Volume: {bar.volume}')
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.open,bar.high,bar.close,bar.low,bar.volume])
        if len(self.data)==62:
               self.data =[]# Initialize variable to store candle
    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextorderId = orderId
        print('The next valid order id is: ', self.nextorderId)

    def start(self):
        self.reqAllOpenOrders()

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        super().openOrder(orderId, contract, order, orderState)
        print( " OrderId:", orderId,
                "Symbol:", contract.symbol,  "Status:", orderState.status)
        dictionary = {"OrderId": orderId,
                       "Symbol": contract.symbol, "Status": orderState.status}
        #if "Submitted" in dictionary :
        #self.order_df = self.order_df.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

def marketOrder(direction,quantity):
    order = Order()
    order.action = direction
    order.orderType = "MKT"
    order.totalQuantity = quantity
    return order

def limitOrder(direction,quantity,lt_price):
    order = Order()
    order.action = direction
    order.orderType = "LMT"
    order.totalQuantity = quantity
    order.lmtPrice = lt_price
    return order


def stopOrder(direction,quantity,st_price):
    order = Order()
    order.action = direction
    order.orderType = "STP"
    order.totalQuantity = quantity
    order.auxPrice = st_price
    return order
app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

# Start the socket in a thread
app.nextorderId = None
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1)  # Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

# Create contract object


contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'DAX'
contract.secType = 'FUT'
contract.exchange = 'Eurex'
contract.currency = 'EUR'
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '202312'

# Request historical candles


starttime = time.time()
timeout = time.time() + 60*60*6
#print(datetime.datetime.now().minute % 5)
# print(datetime.datetime.now().second)

while (time.time() <= timeout ):

    if (datetime.datetime.now().minute % 1==0 )and (datetime.datetime.now().second<40):
        app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, '', '3000 S', '1 min', 'TRADES', 0, 1, False, [])
     
        time.sleep(2)  # sleep to allow enough time for data to be returned
        # headers = ['DateTime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close','Volume']
        # print(dict(zip(headers, app.data)))
        df_data = {}
        df = pandas.DataFrame(app.data)
        df.columns=['DateTime','Open','High','Close','Low','Volume']
       # df['Datetime'] = df['DateTime'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
        # print (df['DateTime'] )
        df1=MACD(df)
        order_id=app.nextorderId
        number=1
        if (  number==1):

            time.sleep(2)
            # order_id=app.nextorderId
            app.placeOrder(order_id,contract,marketOrder("BUY",1))
            app.placeOrder(order_id+1,contract,stopOrder("Sell",1,df["Close"].iloc[-1]-10))
            app.placeOrder(order_id+2,contract,limitOrder("Sell",1,df["Close"].iloc[-1]+20))
           #print(time.localtime(time.time()))

        time.sleep(60*1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
        app.reqOpenOrders()
        time.sleep(2)
        order_list=app.order_df.OrderId.tolist()
        stop_id=order_id+1
        profit_id=order_id+2
        print(stop_id)
        print(profit_id)
        print(order_list)
        if str(int(stop_id)) in order_list:
            app.cancelOrder(profit_id,"")
        if str(int(profit_id))  in order_list:
          app.cancelOrder(stop_id,"")
           




enter code here
```

Comment: You can use EClient Requesting `reqOpenOrders()` function and its corresponding EWrapper Receiving functions. Here is the doc: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/open_orders.html